# Loading Images from Multiple Folders along with their labels into the numpy arrays for Multiclassification Problem

Tags: python

I am working on a multiclass image classification problem and there are over 120 folders inside my training folder and I am trying to load all the images from the 120 folders along with their label in the numpy arrays both X and Y.I am trying the below code But Getting the following error

**ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape**

The code that I am using

```
def loadimgs(path,n = 0):
    '''
    path => Path of train directory or test directory
    '''
    X=[]
    y = []
    cat_dict = {}
    fruit_dict = {}
    curr_y = n

    # we load every alphabet seperately so we can isolate them later
    for fruit in os.listdir(path):
        print("loading Fruit: " + fruit)
        fruit_dict[fruit] = [curr_y,None]
        fruit_path = os.path.join(path,fruit)

        # every letter/category has it's own column in the array, so  load seperately
        for img in os.listdir(fruit_path):
            cat_dict[curr_y] = (fruit, img)
            category_images=[]
            img_path = os.path.join(fruit_path, img)
            # read all the images in the current category
            for filename in img_path:
                image = cv2.imread(filename)
                category_images.append(image)
                y.append(curr_y)

            try:
                X.append(np.stack(category_images))
            # edge case  - last one
            except ValueError as e:
                print(e)
                print("error - category_images:", category_images)
            curr_y += 1
            fruit_dict[fruit][1] = curr_y - 1
    y = np.vstack(y)
    X = np.stack(X)
    return X,y,fruit_dict
```

**My training folder is as follows**
[Training Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOhYQ.png)

**Note: I donot want to use the keras ImageDataGenerator for doing this task**

Comment: Images of different sizes?

Comment: No images are of 100 by 100 size each

Comment: Or is there any other way to load the images from different folders.Please provide the code snippet